# How to display multiple photos via API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

models.py

```
class UserRoom(models.Model):
    objects = None
    categoty = [
        ('President Lux', 'President Lux'),
        ('Lux', 'Lux'),
        ('Double', 'Double'),
        ('Standard', 'Standard'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=categoty, verbose_name='Категория')
    room_num = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    about = models.TextField(verbose_name='Подробности')
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Цена')
    img360 = models.FileField(verbose_name='Фотография в 360')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Номер (About)'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Номера (About)'


class UserImg(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(UserRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='img2')
    img = models.FileField(upload_to='User img', verbose_name='Фотография')
```

how to write in serializers.py so that all data from the database is displayed?

how to write in serializers.py so that all data from the database is displayed?
now when I connect serializers.py it displays either only the first model or pictures from the second and ID of the attached model

```
class UserRoomSer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserRoom
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
views.py

class Test(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = UserRoom.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserRoomSer
```

Comment: In what way have you connected serializers? Show us your views

Comment: Create serializer for `UserImg` and assign `UserRoomSer` to `name` attribute of `UserImg` serializer

Comment: @AnkitTiwari can you show an example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class UserImgSer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserImg
        fields = '__all__'


class UserRoomSer(ModelSerializer):
    images = UserImgSer(source='userimg_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserRoom
        fields = [
            'name', 'room_num', 'about', 'price',
            'img360', 'images',
        ]
```

Just create serializer like above it will create json like this

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "img": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "img": ""
        }
    ],
    "name": "",
    "room_num": "",
    "about": "",
    "price": "",
    "img360": ""
}
```

**Update :**

From **Django REST** [**`Viewsets`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)
update your **views.py** file like this

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class UserRoomViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = UserRoom.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserRoomSer
```

From **Django REST** [**`DefaultRouter`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter)
add this inside your **urls.py** file

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'room', UserRoomViewSet)
urlpatterns = [...all your urls]
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

and if you go to `room` it will show you list of `UserRoom` and if you navigate to `room/<pk>/` you will be able to see details of it

Comment: yes it worked but at a time it displays only one photo at a time and I gave the url address room/1 but then it tracks by photo id and not by room id

Comment: `{
    "name":"",
    "room_num":"",
    "about":"",
    "price":"",
    "img360":""
  },
    "img":""
    "img":""
    "img":""
}` I need it to be like this

Comment: Hello @ЗуфарТангрибергенов check I've updated my answer. I've kept `UserImgSer` becouse it will be useful if you want to serialize only `UserImg` model

Comment: how did you make views.py. i get error all the time

Comment: Hello @ЗуфарТангрибергенов provide your views related to this

Comment: did you implement urls.py like on the updated question ?

Comment: Oh, my bad I'll provide you updated urls.py file

Comment: Hello @ЗуфарТангрибергенов check updated answer

Comment: I did everything as you said but I still get the same error because the 'UserRoom' object does not have the 'images' attribute

Comment: Hello @ЗуфарТангрибергенов it's should work check my code again while creating serializer I've provided images attribute

Comment: Hello @ЗуфарТангрибергенов my bad check I've updated serializer it will work now. To create nested serializer you've to override [create()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) method